# Asus Laptop - Issues with display

Tags: laptop, display, battery

When i turn on my old ASUS laptop the screen stays black, but when i leave it powered on for about 30 minutes and do a restart the display shows up normally.

Why is that happening? Does anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your laptop battery is probably worn out.
I have had the exact same issue. Remove the battery and try to run on AC.

Comment: Removing the battery solved the problem. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Sound like a heat problem. Some soldering joints on your computers motherboard might be having weak connections. Things that doesn't work until they are heated up usually points to a bad solder joint somewhere.

Also it might be the backlight hitting end of life. If you can se the text on screen when looking really close using a flashlight it's the backlight that's gone.

Or it could be the inverter needing a replace.

You can try connecting an external screen to the laptop to see if the graphics card is alright. If so, the reasons above are the most likely faults.